# How to animate a js filtering

Tags: javascript, css, animation, jquery-animate, css-animations

I'm using Bootstrap and I get the JavaScript code for the filterable div elements from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp). It's an easy mode to filter but it's a bit bored without animations.

Because of this, I'm trying to add some animations by CSS or js in my filter code and I don't know how to run it. I tried CSS and js animations but nothing, it's not working.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="myBtnContainer">
    <ul>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">All</button></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('category1')">Category1</button></li>
      <li class="list-inline-item"><button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('category2')">Category2</button></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-lg-3 g-3 pt-2 pb-5">
      <div class="col fade-in-image filterDiv category1 show">
         <a href="http://localhost:8888/test01/projects/project1/">
            <div class="card">
              <img width="480" height="320" src="http://localhost:8888/test01/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/img1.jpeg" class="img-fluid wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy">                
              <div class="hover-project">
                 <h3 class="titol-projecte">Project 1</h3>
                 <p class="location pb-4">Location 1</p>
                 <p class="category">Category 1</p> 
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col fade-in-image filterDiv category-2 show">
         <a href="http://localhost:8888/test01/projects/project2/">
            <div class="card">
              <img width="480" height="320" src="http://localhost:8888/test01/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/img2.jpeg" class="img-fluid wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy">             
              <div class="hover-project">
                 <h3 class="titol-projecte">Project 2</h3>
                 <p class="location pb-4">Location 2</p>
                 <p class="category">Category 2</p> 
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>              
      </div>
   </div>
```

The JavaScript I used:

```
filterSelection("all")
  function filterSelection(c) {
    var x, i;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
    if (c == "all") c = "";
    // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
      if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }
  }

// Show filtered elements
  function w3AddClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
        element.className += " " + arr2[i];
      }
    }
  }

  // Hide elements that are not selected
  function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
        arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1); 
      }
    }
    element.className = arr1.join(" ");
  }

  // Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
  var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
  var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
      this.className += " active";
    });
  }
```

The CSS i used

```
.filterDiv {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: its not possible to animate an element if you use CSS style "hidden". (just for information)

Comment: @hamid if I don't use overflow hidden, how can I fix it?

Comment: I mean if you change display none/visible for Elements, you can't use transition for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one ready example you can use for your code, its pretty amazing in my opinion

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <h4>Filter Programs</h4>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end of row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <div class="programs">
                <button class="filter-btn" data-filter="all">All</button>
                <button class="filter-btn" data-filter=".undergraduate">Undergraduate</button>
                <button class="filter-btn" data-filter=".graduate">Graduate</button>
                <button class="filter-btn" data-filter=".phd">PhD</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end of row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns twelve">
            <h4>Sort Programs</h4>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end of row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns twelve">
            <div class="programs">
                <button class="sort-btn" data-sort="default:asc">Default</button>
                <button class="sort-btn" data-sort="random">Random</button>
                <button class="sort-btn" data-sort="order:asc">Ascending</button>
                <button class="sort-btn" data-sort="year:desc order:desc">Descending<span
                        class="multi">(Multi)</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end of row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <h4>Programs List</h4>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end of row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <ul class="courses" id="mix-wrapper">
                <li class="mix-target undergraduate" data-order="5" data-year="4"><a
                        href="#">Economics<span>(U)</span></a></li>
                <li class="mix-target graduate" data-order="14" data-year="2"><a
                        href="#">Pharmacology<span>(G)</span></a></li>
                <li class="mix-target graduate" data-order="7" data-year="1"><a
                        href="#">Informatics<span>(G)</span></a></li>
                <li class="mix-target phd" data-order="4" data-year="3"><a href="#">Criminology<span>(P)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="mix-target undergraduate" data-order="16" data-year="3"><a
                        href="#">Sociology<span>(U)</span></a></li>
                <li class="mix-target undergraduate" data-order="6" data-year="4"><a
                        href="#">Greek<span>(U)</span></a></li>
                <li class="mix-target phd" data-order="1" data-year="3"><a href="#">Astrophysics<span>(P)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="mix-target undergraduate" data-order="12" data-year="4"><a
                        href="#">Nursing<span>(U)</span></a></li>
                <li class="mix-target undergraduate" data-order="10" data-year="5"><a
                        href="#">Microbiology<span>(U)</span></a></li>
                <li class="mix-target undergraduate" data-order="9" data-year="4"><a
                        href="#">Mathematics<span>(U)</span></a></li>
                <li class="mix-target graduate" data-order="11" data-year="3"><a
                        href="#">Nanoscience<span>(G)</span></a></li>
                <li class="mix-target phd" data-order="2" data-year="2"><a href="#">Biochemistry<span>(P)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="mix-target phd" data-order="13" data-year="3"><a href="#">Pathology<span>(P)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="mix-target graduate" data-order="8" data-year="1"><a
                        href="#">Management<span>(G)</span></a></li>
                <li class="mix-target graduate" data-order="3" data-year="2"><a
                        href="#">Biostatistics<span>(G)</span></a></li>
                <li class="mix-target phd" data-order="15" data-year="4"><a     href="#">Public
                        Health<span>(P)</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC);
body {
    background: #ededed;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 21px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: #d2d2d2;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 3px 0;
}

li {
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

span {
    display: block;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-style: italic;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}

.multi {
    display: inline;
    top: 0;
    left: 3px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.programs,
.courses {
    margin: 8px 0 0 0;
}

.programs {
    font-size: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.programs button {
    outline: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: whitesmoke;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: normal;
    border: 1px solid #ededed;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4px 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #2f6627;
}

.programs button:hover {
    background: #99cfe0;
}

.programs button.programs-filter-btn-active,
.programs button.programs-sort-btn-active {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0px 0px 1px transparent;
    background: #3a9fbf;
    color: white;
}

.courses {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 0;
    background: whitesmoke;
}

.courses li {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 46%;
    margin: 0 2%;
}

.courses a {
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding-top: 12.5px;
    background: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

.courses a:hover {
    background: #99cfe0;
}

.p, .p a {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {

.container {
    width: 95%;
}

.courses a {
    background: #EBEBEB;
    border: none;
}

h4 {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

img {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.programs {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.programs button {
    width: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.courses li {
    width: 21%;
}

}
```

The JS:

```
 mixitup('#mix-wrapper', {
  load: {
    sort: 'order:asc'
  },
    animation: {
    effects: 'fade rotateZ(-180deg)',
    duration: 700
  },
  classNames: {
    block: 'programs',
    elementFilter: 'filter-btn',
    elementSort: 'sort-btn'
  },
  selectors: {
    target: '.mix-target'
  }
});
```